# Converting a R code into C++ for Rcpp implementation

Tags: c++, r, performance, for-loop, rcpp

I have this simple "for loop" written in R which I have to convert in to C++. Following is the reproducible example of R code:

```
# Parameters required 
a <- 1.8
b <- 1
time.dt <- 0.1
yp <- 40 
insp.int <- 7
ph <- 2000

dt <- seq(0,ph,time.dt) # Time sequence
MD.set <- c(seq(insp.int, ph, insp.int), ph) # Decision points to check and set next inspection date

# Initialization
cum.y <- rep(0,length = length(dt)) 
init.y <- 0
flag <- FALSE

# At each iteration, the following loop generates a gamma distributed random number and cum.y keeps taking cumulative sum
# The objective is to return a vector cum.y with a conditional cumulative sum of previous iteration 
# When dt[i] matches any values in MD.Set AND corresponding cum.y[i] is also >= yp it changes the flag to true (the last if)
# At the start of the loop it checks if dt[i] matches any values in MD.Set AND flag is also true. If yes, then cum.y is reset to 0. 

for (i in 2:length(dt)){
  if (dt[i] %in% MD.set && flag == TRUE){
    cum.y[i] <- 0
    init.y <- 0
    flag <- FALSE
    next
  } else {
    cum.y[i] <- init.y + rgamma(n = 1, shape = a*time.dt, scale = b)
    init.y <- cum.y[i]
    if (dt[i] %in% MD.set && cum.y[i] >= yp){
      flag <- TRUE
    }
  }
}

res <- cbind(dt, cum.y)
```

Having no prior experience with C++, I am running into numerous problems when trying to do so. I need to do this conversion only to be able to use it in Rcpp package in R. Because the code runs slowly in R, specially when `time.dt` becomes smaller and I am guessing C++ would do the job faster. Can you help with this?

UPDATE 2:
This is my proposal for the conversion with the help in comments and answer. However, I am not sure what is the equivalent of `next` in `C++`. If I use `continue` it keeps going through the rest of the codes (and execute the ones after `else`. If I use `break` then it comes out of the loop after the condition is true.

```
NumericVector cumy(double a, double b, double timedt, NumericVector dt, NumericVector MDSet, double yp){
  bool flag = false;
  int n = dt.size();
  double total = 0;
  NumericVector out(n);
  unordered_set<int> sampleSet(MDSet.begin(), MDSet.end());
  
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    if (sampleSet.find(dt[i]) != sampleSet.end() && flag == true){
      out[i] = 0;
      total = 0;
      flag = false;
      continue;
    } else {
      out[i] = total + rgamma(1, a*timedt, b)[0];
      total = out[i];
      if (sampleSet.find(dt[i]) != sampleSet.end() && out[i] >= yp){
        flag = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: What problems did you run into? Show your attempt, and what the problems were

Comment: Please check the update. I started with the part after "else" in my R code and added it in the question. Not sure how to convert this %in% of R to C++. I got a hint to use unordered_set and find() but not being able to correctly use it

Comment: Assuming `NumericVector` is just a vector of ints, then you'd do: `unordered_set<int> sampleSet(MDSet.begin(), MDSet.end());`

Comment: So far it's not showing that error. Let me try if I can convert rest of the code to check.

Comment: This line is suspicious: `sampleSet.find(dt[i]) == sampleSet.begin()` as the order in `unordered_set` is not preserved (hence the name) so you do not know which one is the first. Didn't you mean `sampleSet.end()`? (possibly with `!=`)

Comment: @Jérôme Richard, Do you mean `sampleSet.find(dt[i]) != sampleSet.end()`? Aren't these two same?

Comment: @Rel_Ai Yes I mean something like that. No they are not the same: `sampleSet.begin()` is an iterator to an existing item of the `unordered_set` while `sampleSet.end()` is an iterator to a non-existing item returned by functions that does not find things in the container. Note that there are likely other items in between the two iterators, so not being the first does not mean that the item is not found (the returned iterator could be `sampleSet.begin()+1` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting is simply because there's no automatic conversion from `NumericVector` to `std::unordered_set<int>`. You can fix this by doing:

```
std::unordered_set<int> sampleSet( MDSet.begin(), MDSet.end() )
```

This calls the `unordered_set`'s constructor with beginning and end iterators of `MDSet`, which will populate the set with all values.

There's also another issue in your code:

```
if (sampleSet.find(dt[i]) == sampleSet.begin())
```

This will only be true if `dt[i]` is found at the first element of `sampleSet`. From your r code, I'm assuming you are just checking to see if the value `dt[i]` is within `sampleSet`, in which case, you want:

```
if (sampleSet.find(dt[i]) != sampleSet.end())
```

In C++, STL find methods generally return an iterator, and when the value is *not* found, it returns the end iterator, so if `find`'s return value is not `end`, then the value was found within the set.

Comment: So now I think I understand the use of unordered_set. I have updated the code in EDIT2 and I believe I am almost there except for translating the `next` into something equivalent for `C++`. I have found two options `break` and `continue` but they don¨t seem to be appropriate.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to ask another question. You can make a new question which is just specific to that new part. I don't really know what `next` does in `r`, but sounds like `continue` to me.

Comment: Actually it was not about the break statement, it was rather redundant. After I changed unordered_set into double, it seems to be working  (`unordered_set<double> sampleSet(MDSet.begin(), MDSet.end())`).